# Running time for a function in sparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

In sparkR I have a DataFrame 'pgz' which contains data over users. To get all user_id 1 in 'pgz' we simply type

```
filter(pgz, pgz$user_id==1)
```

I have a 'liste' which is a DataFrame. It simply contains number (1,3,4,5,11,25,....). I make this local so I can get the entries.

```
localliste <- collect(liste)
```

Now 'localliste' is a data.frame. 
I then have a function 'lev'

```
lev <- function(j) {
user_id_pgz <- filter(pgz, pgz$user_id==as.numeric(localliste[j]))
t <- as.Date(first(user_id_pgz)[,6][1])
return(t)
}
```

which return 't'. 
When I run this function on small j the function is really fast. It takes about 0.01 sec to calculate t. When I chose a larg j the function takes longer time to calculate t. When j=1002 it takes 40 sec to calculate lev(j).

This is a strange thing. To run the first lines in 'lev' take no time but the line

```
t<-as.Date(first(user_id_pgz)[,6][1])
```

takes time for large j. However it dosent matter if j=1000 or j=50000 the running-time is 40 sec but for j=25 the running-time is about 1 sec. Why is that ?

Comment: Spark does lazy evaluation, the filter is not evaluated until you perform an action like first, which means that both lines are executed at the same moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a minimal example where you get the first item of column 6 per user_id. First I create a DataFrame with user_id column and col6 (like your [,6], then I group by user_id (the same as filtering) and finally, per group I take the first element. In this way, you have outcome for every user_id, perhaps you have less elements in liste?

```
df <- data.frame(user_id=c(1,1,2,2),
                 col6=c("2015-7-31","2015-8-31","2015-8-31","2015-7-31"))

pgz <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, df)
pgz$col6 <- cast(pgz$col6,'date')

results <- collect(agg(group_by(pgz,pgz$user_id),firstCol6 = first(pgz$col6)))
```

Comment: This works perfect and is very fast! Even for my liste wich has 71988 elements. I wish to do 2 things: Make all elements in col6 to a date and subtract them with as.Date("2015-7-30").

Comment: I have edited the example already: col6 is now a date type, but I am still figuring out how to calculate time differences in SparkR.

Comment: When I run your example results gives me user_id 1 2 but firstCol6 gives me NA NA.

Comment: In my setting, it works just fine. Could you provide Some sessioninfo?

Comment: I run it in ubuntu using ./bin/sparkR --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3. And use sqlContext.

Comment: When I use the 'cast' function on my DataFrame pgz it gives me NA. I have just testet it.

Comment: What is the original type of the column you cast?

Comment: The column type is String.

Comment: As long as my date is in the format "2015-7-31" it works, but like "2015-31-7" it gives me NA's, I guess that's the problem.

Comment: I still get NA in all cases. Are you using the exact same code as above and how would you subtract all dates to a fixed date say "2015-6-6" ?

Comment: I haven't found a date-extraction yet. But using the code and the time format from my example gives me no NA's.